# How to make an average line in Tableau dynamic but not across all measures?

Tags: tableau-api

Here is the issue:

I have a measure: Number of Prints
I have a few dimensions: Leader, Associate

I have month over month data, and I would like to show an average across these months. However, I do not want the average line to filter per associate. Rather I would like the average line to show the average for all associates, then I would like it to filter if a leader is chosen, but not an associate.

So for instance

If I have a leader named jack, and one of his reports is an associate named Jill. I want to be able to click on Jack, and it show me the average print volume for all Jack's associates. And if I click on Jill, I want that average to still show me the average across Jack's associates.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need to use context filters. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/filtering_context.html

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems like if you don't include Associate anywhere in your view that should do it. Tableau will only aggregate based on details included in the view.

If you need Associate in the view somewhere, try making a LOD 'level of detail' calculation that excludes Associate:

```
{EXCLUDE [Associate]: AVG([# of Prints])}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve the problem. I'm basically trying to create a dashboard that will show an average line on the month over month chart. I need the average pages printed across all associates, and then filter that average per leader clicked, but not filtered when you click on an associate.

Comment: Can you post an example workbook? Are you putting that line up with reference lines? Is your filter a quick filter? Are the associate and leader names in the same column. I think this will be hard to answer without more details, a sample workbook would be best.